# Doxygen - Generating Dynamic Groups with an Alias Command with a parameter

Tags: dynamic, grouping, doxygen

I'm looking to create a group hierarchy automatically, by having some kind of Alias command. E.g. I want the groups

- Extension Methods

  - String Extensions
  - Stream Extensions
  - ...

to be created with doxygen comments such as

```
/** Documentation for the method
 *  \extension{string} 
 */
public void ExtensionMethod(this string str){
   ... 
}
```

Where `\extension{string}` would map to something like

```
\addtogroup stringExtensions string Extensions
\ingroup ExtnMethods
```

Unfortunately this means that all the documentation written for the method gets associated with the group instead.

The closest I've got is that if you have something like

```
/** \addtogroup stringExtensions string Extensions
 *  \ingroup ExtnMethods
 *  \@{
 *  \@}
 */

/** \ingroup stringExtensions
 *  Documentation for the method
 */ 
public void ExtensionMethod(this string str){
   ... 
}
```

it would work, but this needs the 2 separate comment blocks and I can't find any way to do that using an Alias.

I know that something can probably be achieved with an inputfilter - but I'm hoping something far simpler can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer using inputfilters that was neater than I first supposed - parse the entire file looking for `\extension{...}`, replacing it with an appropriate `\ingroup` command, and then append the desired `\addgroup` commands at the bottom of the file.

This can then be run as an inputfilter

The following is a python script that does this. Note that it doesn't check that what it's replacing is actually within a doxygen comment, but it's good enough for my purposes.

```
#!python

import sys, re


if(len(sys.argv) != 2):
    print "Need exactly one argument, the file to filter"
    exit(1)

extnFinder = re.compile("\\\\extension{(\w+)}")
extnTypes = set();

filename = sys.argv[1]

fileIn = open(filename, "r")

line = fileIn.readline()


def extnSub(matchobj):
    extnTypes.add(matchobj.group(1))
    return "\ingroup %(extn)sExtensions" % {'extn':matchobj.group(1)}


while line:    
    matches = extnFinder.findall(line)
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(extnFinder,extnSub,line))
    line = fileIn.readline()

for extn in extnTypes:
    print "\n\n/**\\addtogroup %(extn)sExtensions %(extn)s Extensions\n\\ingroup ExtnMethods\n */\n" % {'extn':extn}
```